# I keep on getting the same Output despite changing the Input

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to convert an input of roman numerals into the corresponding integer.
However, despite changing the roman numerals I enter i always receive the same answer even tho my code appears alright.Any help would be massively appreciated.
Here's my code:

```
RomanNum=input('Please Enter the Desired number in the form(e.g III):')
def romanToInt(RomanNum):
        #When using roman numerals if the larger numeral comes before the smaller numeral we add them
        #If the smaller numeral comes before larger number we subtract
        
    roman= { "I" : 1, "V" : 5, "X" : 10, "L" : 50, "C" : 100, "D" : 500, "M" : 1000 }
        
    Int=0
        
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i+1<len(s) and roman[s[i]] < roman[s[i+1]]:
            Int-=roman[s[i]]  
        else:
            Int += roman[s[i]]
    return Int

print(romanToInt(RomanNum))
```

I've tried multiple inputs however the answer remains the same.
I expected a changing integer depending on the input of roman numerals.

Comment: Because your parameter is called `RomanNum`, but your loop goes through a variable called `s`, which does not seem to exist.

Comment: You never use RomanNum

Comment: add `s = RomanNum` into your function

Comment: You’re using an IDE where `s` has been assigned already, or you have a global variable you haven’t shown.  Run your code as a script with a fresh interpreter exactly as you’ve shown